# QML without X11

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, qt

Is it possible to run QML files without X_Desktop environment in raspbian Jessie for Raspberry Pi3?

I found this tutorial:  [EGLFS](https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS#Step_by_step) , but I would prefer if it is possible to compile directly on RPi, there is a lot of troubles with cross-compiling and I even didn't succeed to compile Qt, using instructions from this site, on my desktop PC running virtual Ubuntu.